# Verify that $z^{2n+1} = 1$ where the solutions are $\exp({\frac{2ik\pi}{2n+1}})$ where $k$ goes from $-n$ to $n$ doesn't have a solution when $k = 0$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, proof-writing, solution-verification

I've shown that the solutions of $z^{2n+1} = 1$ are the $\exp({\frac{2ik\pi}{2n+1}})$ where $k$ goes from $-n$ to $n$ but now I need to show that it doesn't have a solution when $k = 0$.

So I tried to replace $k$ with $0$ in $\exp({\frac{2ik\pi}{2n+1}})$ and I obtain $\exp({\frac{0}{2n+1}}) = \exp(0) = 1$. So the equation $z^{2n+1} = 1$ still holds when $k = 0$. How do I show that there is no solution when $k=0$ ? Did I make any mistakes in my reasoning ?

In the very first question i've shown that if $P_{n}(x)=\frac{(x+i)^{(2n+1)} - (x-i)^{(2n+1)}}{2i} = 0$ then x verify $(\frac{x+i}{x-i})^{2n+1} = 1$

Comment: There is no $k$ in the equation $z^{2n+1} = 1$.

Comment: No, there is no error. Are you sure about the statement of the problem?

Comment: Yes, in the previous question I needed to check that the solution to the equations $z^{2n+1} = 1$ are the $\exp({\frac{2ik\pi}{2n+1}})$, and the next question is "Verify that there is no solution when $k=0$. In the very first question i've shown that if $ P_{n}(x)=\frac{(x+i)^{(2n+1)} - (x-i)^{(2n+1)}}{2i} = 0$ then $x$ verify $(\frac{x+1}{x-1})^{2n+1} = 1$

Comment: Ah, there's an important difference between solving $z^{2n+1}=1$ and solving $\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^{2n+1} = 1$. There's no issue with $k=0$ in the $z$ equation, but in the $x$ equation....

Comment: Sorry I made a typo, it's $(\frac{x+i}{x-i})^{2n+1}$. So $P_n(x)=0$ when $(\frac{x+i}{x-i})^{2n+1} = \exp(\frac{2ik\pi}{2n+1})$

Comment: $\frac{x+i}{x-i}  = e^0$, $\frac{x+i}{x-i}  = 1$, $x+i= x-i$, $i = -i$, there is a contradiction, so $k = 0$ isn't a solution. Is my reasoning right ?

Answer (score 1):

Please see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3949938/how-to-obtain-the-complete-factorization-of-p-nx-fracxi2n1-x-i) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3919966/show-that-the-unique-solution-of-p-nx-0-is-x-i-frace2i-theta1e2i/3922698#3922698) and also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3948892/give-the-complete-factorization-of-p-nx-fracxi2n1-x-i2n12i) for a complete solution.

We show that $x=\frac{1}{\tan \theta_k} = \frac{\cos \theta}{\sin \theta} = i\frac{e^{i2\theta}+1}{e^{2i\theta}-1}$ where $k \in \{ \mp1,\mp2,\cdots,\mp n\}$ and $\theta_k = \frac{k\pi}{2n+1}$.

Please also see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3922178/show-that-the-solution-of-p-nx-0-is-x-i-frace2i-theta1e2i-theta/3950785#3950785).