# Show that the unique solution of $P_n(X) = 0$ is $x=i\frac{e^{2i\theta}+1}{e^{2i\theta}-1}=\frac{1}{\tan(\theta)}$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, proof-writing, roots

I need to how that when $ k \neq 0$, the unique solution of $P_n(X)=\frac{(X+i)^{2n+1} - (X - i)^{2n+1}}{2i} = 0$ is $ x=i\frac{e^{2i\theta}+1}{e^{2i\theta}-1}=\frac{1}{\tan(\theta)} $ with $\theta=\frac{k\pi}{2n+1} \in ]-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}[ \backslash {0}$.

In the previous questions I've shown that there is no solutions when $k=0$, that if $P_n(x) = 0$, then $x$ verify $(\frac{x+i}{x-i})^{2n+1} = 1$, and that $P_n(x) = 0$ when $\frac{x+i}{x-i} = \exp(\frac{2ik\pi}{2n+1})$ with $k$ between $-n$ and $n$.

I don't really know where to start with this question. Do i just need to replace x in the polynomial with what is said to be the unique solution ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "unique solution."  When $n=1$, $P_n(x)=3x^2-1$ and $P_n(x)=0$ has two solutions.  When $n=2$, $P_n(x) = 5x^4 -10x^2+1$ and $P_n(x)=0$ has four solutions, etc.

Comment: Apparently when $ k \neq 0$ we obtain a unique solution that is $ x=i\frac{e^{2i\theta}+1}{e^{2i\theta}-1}=\frac{1}{\tan(\theta)} $ / My guess is that I need t replace $x$ in $\frac{x+i}{x-i} = \exp(\frac{2ik\pi}{2n+1})$ and show that both sides are true ?

Comment: Okay, so $\frac{1}{\tan \theta}$ is one solution.  But there are multiple solutions to $P_n(x)=0.$   The use of the word _unique_ seems misleading.  Anyway, yes, it is one of the solutions.

Comment: So now when I simplify I get $\frac{1+tan(\theta)}{1-tan(\theta)}$. How can i show that the equality is true ?

Comment: All of the solutions are of the form $1/\tan \theta$, and $\theta=\theta(k)$  for various $k$.

Answer (score 1):

We want the solutions to $$(x+i)^{2n+1} - (x-i)^{2n+1} =0.$$

Assume $x$ is real and $z=x+i = r e^{i\theta}$ so that $z^*=x-i=re^{-i\theta}$ is the conjugate of $z$.

Substituting and rearranging:

$$z^{2n+1} = {z^\ast}^{2n+1}$$

$$e^{i(2n+1)\theta}=e^{-i(2n+1)\theta}$$

$$e^{i2(2n+1)\theta}=1=e^{2\pi k i}$$

so $$\theta = \frac{k\pi}{2n+1}$$

but $z=x+i$ thus $\Im z \ne 0$, so $k\ne 0$ nor is $k$ a multiple of $2n+1.$

$$x=\Re \left(re^{i\theta}\right)=r\cos \theta, \quad { \text{and} }\quad
 1=\Im \left(re^{i\theta}\right)=r\sin \theta,$$

so $r = 1/\sin \theta$ and $$x=\frac{\cos \theta}{\sin \theta}=\cot \theta=\frac{1}{\tan \theta} =i \frac{e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}}{e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}}=i\frac{e^{2i\theta}+1}{e^{2i\theta}-1}.$$

One indexing is $k\in \{1,2,\cdots, 2n\}.$

The solution is not unique.  $P_n$ is a polynomial of order $2n$, and $P_n(x)=0$ has $2n$ solutions.

$$\begin{aligned} P_n(x)&= \frac{1}{2i}\left[(x+i)^{2n+1}-(x-i)^{2n+1}\right]\\&=\frac{1}{2i} \left[ \sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} \pmatrix{2n+1\\k}x^k i^{2n+1-k}-\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} \pmatrix{2n+1\\k}x^k (-i)^{2n+1-k}\right]\\ &=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \pmatrix{2n+1\\2k}x^{2k} (-1)^{k+n}\\&=(2n+1)x^{2n}-\pmatrix{2n+1\\2n-2}x^{2n-2} + \cdots +(-1)^n.\end{aligned}$$

Please see [**a continuation of the discussion**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3949938/how-to-obtain-the-complete-factorization-of-p-nx-fracxi2n1-x-i) for further developments.

Comment: Isn't it $2n-2$ at the bottome of the binomial coefficient of the step 3 ? $2k$ when $k=n-1$ is equal to $2n-2$ ? Do I just need to replace $x$ with $\cot(\theta)$ ? I tried it but I can't manage to compute the sum

Comment: Yes, you are right!  Should be $2n-2.$  Thank you!

Comment: when i develop the expression i get $(2n+1)((\cot(\theta))^{2n} - \frac{(2n)(2n-1)}{3!}(\cot(\theta))^{2n-2}) + ...)$ It somewhat looks like the factorization $(2n+1)(X-t)(X-t_1)$ where the $t$ are the roots. Is it the right answer? It probably needs to be better formalized though. Thanks for your help

Comment: You are welcome.