# Showing that if $P_n(X)=\frac{(X+i)^{2n+1} - (X-i)^{2n+1}}{2i} = 0$, then x verify $(\frac{x+i}{x-i})^{2n+1} = 1$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, proof-writing, solution-verification

I need to show that if $P_n(X)=\frac{(X+i)^{2n+1} -  (X-i)^{2n+1}}{2i} = 0$, then x verify $(\frac{x+i}{x-i})^{2n+1} = 1$.

Here is what i have done:
$$P_n(X)=\frac{(X+i)^{2n+1} -  (X-i)^{2n+1}}{2i} = 0 \\ (X+i)^{2n+1}-(X-i)^{2n+1} = 0*2i = 0 \\ (X+i)^{2n+1} = (X-i)^{2n+1} \\ \frac{(X+i)^{2n+1}}{(X-i)^{2n+1}} = 1 \\ \left(\frac{X+i}{X-i}\right)^{2n+1} = 1$$

Is my reasoning correct ?

Comment: Yes it is ..........

Comment: Also before dividing by $(x-i)^{2n+1},$ you must verify that $i$ does not satisfy this equation.

Comment: What do you mean by verifying that $i$ does no t satisfy this equation ?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the discussion [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3919966/show-that-the-unique-solution-of-p-nx-0-is-x-i-frace2i-theta1e2i/3922698#3922698) where it is mentioned that $z=x+i$, $z^\ast=x-i$ and $z^{2n+1}={z^{\ast}}^{2n+1}$.  Another way to write this is $$\left(\frac{x+i}{x-i}\right)^{2n+1} = 1.$$