# Show that the solution of $P_n(X) = 0$ is $x=i\frac{e^{2i\theta}+1}{e^{2i\theta}-1}=\frac{1}{\tan(\theta)}$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, proof-writing

I need to how that when $ k \neq 0$, we obtain a unique solution of $P_n(X)=\frac{(X+i)^{2n+1} - (X - i)^{2n+1}}{2i} = 0$ is $ x=i\frac{e^{2i\theta}+1}{e^{2i\theta}-1}=\frac{1}{\tan(\theta)} $ with $\theta=\frac{k\pi}{2n+1} \in ]-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}[ \backslash {0}$.

In the previous questions I've shown that there are no solutions when $k=0$, that if $P_n(x) = 0$, then $x$ verify $(\frac{x+i}{x-i})^{2n+1} = 1$, and that $P_n(x) = 0$ when $\frac{x+i}{x-i} = \exp(\frac{2ik\pi}{2n+1})$ with $k$ between $-n$ and $n$.

So my guess is that I need to replace $x$ in $\frac{x+i}{x-i}$ by $\frac{1}{tan(\theta)}$ and show that the equation $\frac{x+i}{x-i} = \exp(\frac{2ik\pi}{2n+1})$ with $k$ between $-n$ and $n$ is true? But I'm stuck and don't really know how to go further.

Answer (score 1):

Right, please see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3949938/how-to-obtain-the-complete-factorization-of-p-nx-fracxi2n1-x-i) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3919966/show-that-the-unique-solution-of-p-nx-0-is-x-i-frace2i-theta1e2i/3922698#3922698) and also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3948892/give-the-complete-factorization-of-p-nx-fracxi2n1-x-i2n12i) for a rather complete solution.

There, we show that $x=\frac{1}{\tan \theta_k} = \frac{\cos \theta}{\sin \theta} = i\frac{e^{i2\theta}+1}{e^{2i\theta}-1}$ where $k \in \{ \mp1,\mp2,\cdots,\mp n\}$ and $\theta_k = \frac{k\pi}{2n+1}$.