# Give the complete factorization of $P_n(X)=\frac{(X+i)^{2n+1} - (X-i)^{2n+1}}{2i} = 0$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, factoring

I need to give the complete factorization of $P_n(X)=\frac{(X+i)^{2n+1} - (X-i)^{2n+1}}{2i} = 0$ and show that $P_n(X)=(2n+1)\prod_{k=1}^{n}(X^2-\frac{1}{t_{n,k}^{2}})$ with $t_{n,k}^{2}=\tan(\frac{k\pi}{2n+1})$.

Here is what I have done so far:
$$P_n(X)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-k}\binom{2n+1}{2k}X^{2k}=(2n+1)\left(X^{2n}+(-1)\frac{(1-2n)}{3}X^{2n-2}+...+(-1)^{n-1}nX^2+\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\right)$$

but now i don't know how to progress further to get the asked result.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3949938/how-to-obtain-the-complete-factorization-of-p-nx-fracxi2n1-x-i) for the solution.

Also, please see the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3919966/show-that-the-unique-solution-of-p-nx-0-is-x-i-frace2i-theta1e2i/3922698#3922698).